# Entity View Attachments (EVA) with multiple contextual filters?

Tags: organic-groups, views

I have the following content types which are also organic groups;

Country (group)
 
Region (subgroup of country) 
Area (subgroup of region) 
Neighborhood (subgroup of area)
Facilities (subgroup of Neighborhood)

I have a a leaflet map view as an Entity View Attachment with these Entity content settings;

Entity type: Node
Bundles: Country
Arguments: id

I would like create country maps showing all of its corresponding subgroups ie: Regions, Areas, Neighborhoods and Facilities.

Unfortunately I have only managed to get the "Region" content type appearing on the map using the "OG membership: Group ID" as a contextual filter argument and using "current og from context" for "When the filter value is NOT available".

Any ideas for how I can use multiple arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Querying the configured multiple contextual filter isn't working as i expected first and I spent lot of time to figure out why, then finally the solution was found:

Instead of `Content: The name of Taxonomy (taxonomy_vocabulary_#)` you need to select `Content: Has taxonomy term ID` *Contextual filter* and enable *Allow multiple values* to able to use multiple values in the form of `1+2+3` (for `OR`) or `1,2,3` (for `AND`).
If You have another *Contextual filter* configured, you can separate the query with "/".